# Redux state not setting

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create React application with a Redux store which can set a user's ID. Here is my:

Reducer:

```
const cmsDefaultState = {
  cmsNum: "",
};

export default (state = cmsDefaultState, action) => {

  switch (action.type){

    case 'SET_CMS_ID':
    console.log("triggered");
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        cmsNum: action.cmsNum
      });

    default:
      return state;
  }

};
```

Methods:

```
export const setCMSId = (cmsNum = '') => ({
  type: 'SET_CMS_ID',
  cmsNum
});
```

And inside my index.js, this is what I have:

```
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './redux/configureStore.js'

import { setCMSId } from './redux/methods.js'
const store = configureStore();

store.dispatch(setCMSId({cmsNum: "Hello"}));
console.log("[" + store.getState().cmsNum + "]");

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

So essentially, on console.log, I should have printed `[Hello]` but instead it's printing `[[object Object]]`

Thoughts? Not sure where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Where are you calling `connect`?  Where is `App`?

Comment: You're dispatching an object `{cmsNum: "Hello"}` not a string. So your final state looks like `{cmsNum: {cmsNum: "Hello"}}`

Comment: You pass JSON object `{cmsNum: "Hello"}` to setCMSId, but as I can see you waiting only string value. Change to `setCMSId("Hello")`

Comment: Oh I'm so silly. Thanks so much.